# How can you test an angualar service while mocking a dependency of that service?

Tags: angularjs, testing

So I have two services:

```
// The service I'm testing
angular.module("m").service("myService", function(otherService) { ... })

// the service I'd like to mock while testing
angular.module("m").service("otherService", function() { ... })


describe("my test", function() {

  var myService = null;

  beforeEach(module('m'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     // but I want it to get injected with 'otherService'
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     myService = $injector.get("myService")
  })

  it ('test myService', function() {

  })   
})
```

I want to mock out `otherService` before it's injected into `myService` and I test the instance of `myService` in follow up `it` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `$provide` service to replace the `otherService` implementation with a mocked one. Here you go:

```
describe('my test', function() {
    var myService, otherServiceMock;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('m');

        otherServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('otherService', [...]);

        module(function($provide) {
            // Replaces the service with a mock object
            $provide.value('otherService', otherServiceMock);
        });

        inject(function(_myService_) {
            myService = _myService_;
        });
    });
});
```

Check out the [$provide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can just mock the methods of the service in question on the fly

```
var myService, otherService;

beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
  myService = $injector.get('myService');
  otherService = $injector.get('otherService');
}));

it('calls otherService.doOther when doSomething is called', function() {
  spyOn(otherService, 'doOther');
  myService.doSomething();
  expect(otherService.doOther).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

With the jasmine spies, you can for example test outcomes with different return values, etc.

```
it('doesSomething returns true when otherService.doOther returns false', function() {
  spyOn(otherService, 'doOther').andReturn(false);
  expect(myService.doSomething()).toBeTruthy();
});
```